# Parse pdf to txt Service on Spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, parsing, pdfbox

I want to parse my pdf into a txt file using PDFBox on the server. I call the service of the parsing on my controller. I have an action of uploading a file and once it is uploaded, I add the service of the parsing into txt to handle my text file on my saveDirectoryFolder.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/savefiles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public String crunchifySave(
            @ModelAttribute("uploadForm") irFileUpload uploadForm,
            Model map) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {


        String saveDirectory = "C://raexFiles//";

        List<MultipartFile> crunchifyFiles = uploadForm.getFiles();

        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (null != crunchifyFiles && crunchifyFiles.size() > 0) {

            for (MultipartFile multipartFile : crunchifyFiles) {

                String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
                if (!"".equalsIgnoreCase(fileName)) {

                    // Handle file content - multipartFile.getInputStream()
                    File myfile = new File(saveDirectory + fileName);
                     multipartFile.transferTo(myfile);  

                  // Here I call the service of the parse
                     parse.toTxt(myfile , saveDirectory + fileName);


                    fileNames.add(fileName);                                  
                }

            }
        }
        map.addAttribute("files", fileNames);
        return "uploadfile";
    }
}
```

My service of parsing have a method with two attributes (the file, and the target of the txt file) :

```
@Service("PaseService")
@Transactional
public class ParseServiceImpl implements ParseService{

    String content;


    @Override
    public void toTxt(File file, String pathFile) throws IOException {      

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

            PDFTextStripper s = new PDFTextStripper();
            content = s.getText(document);

            // Parser La Sortie Dans Un Fichier txt
               try( PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(pathFile +  ".txt"))){
                    out.println(content);
            }           
        }
}
```

Please can anyone see a problem with my code

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. To review your code? Or is something not working the way you want - if so, please describe what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: There's a typo in `@Service("PaseService")`, this should probably be `@Service("ParseService")`

Comment: Do you get any error, or its just not working well? Can you attach more informations?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr There is no problem on the annotation I fix it but no results

Comment: @Hdevoxxed next step would be to debug this to check whether the code is called. Specifically, is `toTxt(File file, String pathFile)` ever called?

Comment: There is no change on my view .. There is no exception or error

Comment: @Hdevoxxed that isn't an answer to my question.